# With CRA upgrade from 3.4.1 to 4.0.3 tests are running much slower

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, cra

I have a CRA project which I updated from `3.4.1` to `4.0.3`
With the update on `4.x.x` it also updated Jest to version `26.x.x`

After this update, the tests are 3x slower than before the upgrade. I suspect it has to do with the new Jest version.

Some important things to mention:

- There are 1800 test suites with almost 10k tests;
- the tests are 3x slower when run with `runInBand`, they take approx. 1700 seconds compared to approx. 600 seconds before the update;
- the tests are running faster without `runInband` option but they take almost the entire CPU resources and memory;
- adding `--maxWorkers` with any value flag does not help too much;
- the script for the tests is run via react-app-rewired: `"test": "react-app-rewired test"`;
- jest config in package.json looks like this:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": [
    "./jest.overrides.js",
    "jest-canvas-mock"
  ],
  "resetMocks": false
},
```

- `jest.overrides.js` file contains:

```
const { error } = console;

console.error = (message, ...rest) => {
  error.apply(console, [message, ...rest]);

  if (message instanceof Error) {
    throw message;
  }

  throw new Error(message);
};
```

Removing the content of this file does not help either (I just give it a try).

- I removed the `react-app-rewired` and run the tests via `react-scripts` and the speed is the same (slow).

Does anyone encounter a similar situation? Is there a way to improve the speed of the tests?
I do not understand why an upgrade can cause this kind of regression.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am also experiencing a similar problem, after upgrading my packages the jest tests appear to take **MUCH** longer. I went from 2 seconds to 60+ seconds, it appears to effect multiple Jest versions (on the major revisions). I am not sure which minor update causes this problem just yet.

I am using Vue JS and TS Jest with the jest plugin, but getting same symptoms you are basically.

Comment: @Ambidex it is possible that there is an issue with Node versions above 16.10
I heard that Node 16.13 upgraded V8 which just makes memory leaks from node 14 much more visible.
I did not tested myself yet but at least from the tests done by a colleague that handles the DevOps part this was the conclusion.

Comment: Stumbled upon this Q after seeing similar behavior in an upgrade to react-scripts v4. There's a (still-open) issue on the Jest repo re: a perf regression in v25 that might be related: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9457. react-scripts v3 was on Jest v24 before.